# Select random row without duplication using entity framework4.5 mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have tried following code i need to random row with out duplication based on the NAME field.

> List list = db.Logos.Where(a => a.LogoName !=
>   "empty.png").OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())  .GroupBy(a => a.LogoName)
>   .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Take(8).ToList();

but i did not get randomly but i have tried another code which is shuffling correctly but duplicate code could not apply, code below

> List list = (from c in db.Logos
>                                      where c.LogoName != "empty.png"
>                                      select c).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3).ToList();

please help how to select  both duplication and random rows.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try the below one?

```
var result = (from logo in db.Logos
             where (logo.LogoName != "empty.png")
             orderby logo.LogoName
             select logo).Distinct();
```

Comment: This code is fine but i need randomly select rows with that code

Comment: Do you want random records, for each query execution?

Comment: Are you storing the previous query result somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the ordering before the grouping. That looses the ordering completely.

```
db.Logos
.Where(a => a.LogoName != "empty.png")
.GroupBy(a => a.LogoName)
.Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
.Take(8)
.ToList();
```

Performance of this query will not be so great, but that does not seem to be your primary concern. It will be fast on small data sets.